# VLC subtitles: Why do I get these weird characters?

Tags: video, vlc, subtitle

When I load a subtitles file with VLC I get these weird characters:

[image]

This doesn't happen with other subtitles files, so I was wondering what's this different encoding. The file is included in the mkv format, so I can't open it with a text editor.

Comment: Always with MKV? Or just this particular file?

Comment: That is the Apple last resort font.  It appears when for some reason the app cannot access the particular font designated.  Sometimes trashing font caches can help.